# Copy Cell Down to Last Row with Dynamic Cell References

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic

I am using the `Find` method to identify columns which have been populated with headers. Then offsetting my selection down one row and entering either a string or a formula. Then I want to paste my selection down the column to the Last populated row. It's really just the syntax of the last line of the code I'm looking to repair.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Integer
i = 0
g = 0
Dim Rtitles(3) As String

Rtitles(0) = "NAME OF M4"
Rtitles(1) = "M4 NUMBER"
Rtitles(2) = "X-Ref ID"
Rtitles(3) = "ADDRESS ID"

Range("A1").Select

Do Until i = 17
    If ActiveCell <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        i = i + 1
    Else
        ActiveCell = Rtitles(g)
        g = g + 1
    End If
Loop

'Determines Last Row
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048575, 3).End(xlUp).Row


'This section Populates the Four newly titled columns
i = 0
Do Until i = 4

Cells.Find(What:=Rtitles(i), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
[...]
If i = 2 Then ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(FIND(""_"",RC[-1])),RC[-1],LEFT(RC[-1],LEN(RC[-1])-3))"
Range(ActiveCell).AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow,activecolumn))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's really just the syntax of the last line of the code I'm looking to repair.

There is no need to use AutoFill. You can enter a formula in the entire range in one go.

Replace

```
Range(ActiveCell).AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Cells(LastRow,activecolumn))
```

with

```
Dim ColName As String

'~~> Gets the Column Letter of active cell
ColName = Split(Cells(, ActiveCell.Column).Address, "$")(1)

Range(ActiveCell.Address & ":" & ColName & lastrow).Formula = _
Range(ActiveCell.Address).Formula
```

**EDIT**

BTW do not use `LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048575, 3).End(xlUp).Row` to find the last row. One should never hard code values. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find last row.

Comment: Great advice, this really helps expand my "toolbox" in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row in column 3 ("C"), use:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to know "How to find the last row" :)